# Connecting to Android Emulator through VNC

Tags: node.js, canvas, android-emulator, vnc, vnc-viewer

How can we connect to Android emulator through VNC with the help of [noVNC](http://kanaka.github.com/noVNC/noVNC/vnc.html) using javascript?
i would like to render the emulator on my browser.How can that be done.thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can start the emulator on the console with `emulator -avd <the avd name>` and add options for qemu with `-qemu` in your case `-qemu -vnc :2` will start a VNC server listening at Port `5902`.
If you get an error, that your keymap was not found you can creating a symlink from `android-sdks/tools/keymaps` to the keymaps folder of your local qemu install.

Until now I couldn't find out, how to forward the mouse to the VNC server.

Comment: I am using novnc and getting this error on novnc server console

  8: 127.0.0.1: ignoring socket not ready
  9: 127.0.0.1: ignoring socket not ready
 10: 127.0.0.1: ignoring socket not ready
 11: 127.0.0.1: ignoring socket not ready
 13: 127.0.0.1: ignoring socket not ready
 12: 127.0.0.1: ignoring socket not ready

did you got any idea how to do it ?

Comment: @white_gecko did you ever find out how to forward mouse/keyboard to the vnc server running on the android emulator?

Answer (score 0):

You'll be probably better running a vnc server *inside* your emulator.

Install a vnc server on your emulator ([Fastdroid](https://code.google.com/p/fastdroid-vnc/) is fine).

Now, you can start your emulator without window using

```
emulator -avd avd_name -no-window -qemu
```