# Android emulator + QEMU VNC

Tags: android, qemu, vnc

I'm trying to run the emulator like this:

```
emulator -avd name -qemu -vnc :4
```

And I get an error:

> Could not read keymap file: 'en-us'

Is it an error of the emulator or QEMU's error? How can I fix it?

I have read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847271/connecting-to-android-emulator-through-vnc) and created a symlink from `/urs/local/Cellar/qemu/1.7.0_1/share/qemu/keymaps` to my `android-sdk/tools` folder, but it didn't help. (I use [OS X v10.9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mavericks) (Mavericks).)

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a QEMU thing.

Create this folder: *(android-sdk)/tools/keymaps*

Create an empty file in *(android-sdk)/tools/keymaps* called *en-us*.

The emulator should start now.

Answer (score 2):

There might be a shorter way, but this method solved my problem.

- You can download the latest source tar ball from official [QEMU Download](http://wiki.qemu.org/Download) page.
- Then extract it to somewhere else.
- You can find a **keymaps** directory in the **pc-bios** subfolder.
- You may copy the **keymaps** folder to your **[ANDROID_SDK]/tools/** directory.

Now you can use an arbitrary keymap file:

```
emulator -avd name -qemu -vnc :4 -k tr
```

**Note:**

In some situations you must copy the `keymaps` folder under **[ANDROID_SDK]/tools/lib/pc-bios/**

Comment: For what it's worth, I was only able to resolve the error by creating a symlink from `/usr/share/qemu/keymaps` to `$ANDROID_SDK/tools/lib/pc-bios/keymaps`